# why can you not enable bottom halves when irqs are disabled?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, irq, softirq

In `__local_bh_enable`, we have a

```
WARN_ON_ONCE(!irqs_disabled());
```

I'm wondering what the purpose of this warning is -- I would imagine you would want to be able to renable bottomhalves when in say  `spinlock_irq` protected code...   (note: I'm looking at linux 3.4 code here, but it also seems to be in 4.1).